# Will there be a Blender 3.x LTS and if yes, when?

Tags: versions

According to this post (https://code.blender.org/2020/02/release-planning-2020-2025/) referenced at the bottom of the official Blender LTS download page, Blender 3.3 LTS was proposed to release in May of this year, but that didn't seem to happen (yet?).
In fact, only Blender 2 has LTS releases so far, with the latest one (2.93 LTS) initially released in June 2021.

This left me wondering:

- Is there still a plan for Blender 3 to have LTS releases?
- If yes, is it known when we can expect the first one and which minor version it will be based on?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your question is more of guess at the moment, only the developers have the answer. The site is for questions about how to do things in Blender. If you are looking fo a discussion type, try with Blender artists or Blender in Reddit.

Comment: @Emir Not really. It's not a guess. There are plans. They sometimes are late, but still happen.

Comment: yeah but still i think this question likely does not belong on this site. voting to close.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys We as users can only guess, because as you said, sometimes they are late, the correct date for a release to be available can only be answer by the Blender Fundation

Comment: @sefexin245 By the way, you could watch Blender Today on youtube, it's a live stream and you can ask the question there

Comment: We can be quite sure that - yes, it is going to be released, yes, it will be LTS and that it will happen some time during the next month.

Comment: This is not guessing. The releases are planned. They do happen as planned within some margins. While this is not the most valuable question for the community since it's going to expire in a month or so, I see nothing wrong with it. It is in fact wrong to say that we don't know - the development process and plans are public.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Many other questions might have answers that are not guessing, that doesn't automatically qualify for being on-topic. To me this is a question regarding Blender's development, which is considered off-topic according to this community post (4.): [What questions should be definitely off-topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I don't know... It says "Developing Blender (in C/C++)..." So... not so clear to me. It's not about developing Blender in C, it's about releases of Blender that is vaguely related to development in general... It may be that it should be off topic. Anyway I see no big deal about answering it. Do you think we will not see Blender 3.3 LTS released next month? We will. :D

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I thought of the C/C++ as distinction to Python scripting which is considered on-topic, and not every example has to be explicitly mentioned. Since you've answered and it's accepted already it doesn't matter much anyway. And what does me believing if we see Blender 3.3 LTS next month or not have to do with considering it off-topic? never said your answer is wrong... I just think the question is of no future value for users struggling with working in Blender. And the closer the release date is, the more irrelevant the question is on a site like this. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Something I was thinking as well. The question seems to have no long term value. But if a new user does not know anything about Blender's development, asks this question here ... gets an answer "well - who knows - Blender will be released whenever the devs feel like it and LTS may or may not be a thing and you are wrong to even ask this" Well that's misleading in my view. The releases are planed strictly and LTS versions are a serious thing meant for big studios to be able to trust Blender and the way its developed. They are here to stay. I think that's kind of important to make clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it [here](https://code.blender.org/2020/02/release-planning-2020-2025/#30-series) that version 3.3 is going to be LTS. So once it is released, it is going to be LTS. Blender 3.3 is the next version that is going to be released. We can see it [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/) that it is currently in beta stage. I believe it will be released some time next month. A quick web search finds a few mentions of September 7 like [here](https://developer.blender.org/project/view/142/) so even if it's late a few days, it is going to happen.

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/project/view/142/